# Regex and Pattern Matching in Scala Part II

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

As a follow-up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636610/regex-and-pattern-matching-in-scala) question

Here is some code that compiles and runs correctly, using captures.

```
val myString = "ACATCGTAGCTGCTAGCTG"

val nucCap = "([ACTG]+)".r

myString match {
   case nucCap(myNuc) => println("dna:"+myNuc)
   case _ => println("not dna")
}

>scala scalaTest.scala 
dna:ACATCGTAGCTGCTAGCTG
```

Here is simpler code, without capture, that does not compile.

```
val myString = "ACATCGTAGCTGCTAGCTG"

val nuc = "[ACGT]+".r

myString match {
     case nuc => println("dna")
     case _ => println("not dna")
}

>scala scalaTest.scala
scalaTest.scala:7: error: unreachable code
```

Seems like the matching should return a boolean regardless of whether a capture is used.
What is going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `match` block, `nuc` is a pattern variable and does not refer to the `nuc` in the enclosing scope. This makes the default case unreachable because the simple pattern `nuc` will match anything.

An empty pair of parentheses on `nuc` will make the syntactic sugar work and call the `unapplySeq` method on the Regex:

```
myString match {
  case nuc() => println("dna")
  case _ => println("not dna")
}
```

One way to avoid this pitfall is to rename `nuc` to `Nuc`. Starting with an uppercase letter makes it a stable identifier, so that it refers to the `Nuc` in the enclosing scope, rather than being treated by the compiler as a pattern variable.

```
val Nuc = "[ACGT]+".r
myString match {
  case Nuc => println("dna")
  case _ => println("not dna")
}
```

The above will print `"not dna"`, because here we are simply comparing `Nuc` to `myString`, and they are not equal. It's a bug, but maybe a less confusing one!

Adding the parentheses will have the desired effect in this case too:

```
myString match {
  case Nuc() => println("dna")
  case _ => println("not dna")
}
// prints "dna"
```

---

By the way, it is not a boolean that is being returned, but an `Option[List[String]]`:

```
scala> nuc.unapplySeq(myString)
res17: Option[List[String]] = Some(List())
scala> nucCap.unapplySeq(myString)
res18: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(ACATCGTAGCTGCTAGCTG))
```

Comment: not to nitpick but why does it say the default case is unreachable (case _ => println("not dna"))