# Matching against a regular expression in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I fairly frequently match strings against regular expressions.  In Java:

java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\w+").matcher("this_is").matches

Ouch.  Scala has many alternatives.

1. `"\\w+".r.pattern.matcher("this_is").matches`
2. `"this_is".matches("\\w+")`
3. `"\\w+".r unapplySeq "this_is" isDefined`
4. `val R = "\\w+".r; "this_is" match { case R() => true; case _ => false}`

The first is just as heavy-weight as the Java code.

The problem with the second is that you can't supply a compiled pattern (`"this_is".matches("\\w+".r")`).  (This seems to be an anti-pattern since almost every time there is a method that takes a regex to compile there is an overload that takes a regex).

The problem with the third is that it abuses `unapplySeq` and thus is cryptic.

The fourth is great when decomposing parts of a regular expression, but is too heavy-weight when you only want a boolean result.

Am I missing an easy way to check for matches against a regular expression?  Is there a reason why `String#matches(regex: Regex): Boolean` is not defined?  In fact, where is `String#matches(uncompiled: String): Boolean` defined?

Comment: It's worth noting that `String#matches(string: String)` is not defined by either the 2.9 spec or the [StringLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringLike) type from the standard library. It is, in fact, an artifact of the definition of [Strings in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by too heavy-weight in the first example?  Do you mean that the code is too long, or do you mean that it's doing too much work?

Comment: too much code, the work is exactly what I want

Comment: @ig0774, thanks for that point.  I was confused why I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can define a pattern like this :

```
scala> val Email = """(\w+)@([\w\.]+)""".r
```

`findFirstIn` will return `Some[String]` if it matches or else `None`.

```
scala> Email.findFirstIn("test@example.com")
res1: Option[String] = Some(test@example.com)

scala> Email.findFirstIn("test")
rest2: Option[String] = None
```

You could even extract :

```
scala> val Email(name, domain) = "test@example.com"
name: String = test
domain: String = example.com
```

Finally, you can also use conventional `String.matches` method (and even recycle the previously defined `Email Regexp` :

```
scala> "david@example.com".matches(Email.toString)
res6: Boolean = true
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: @schmmd don't forget `.r` to build a `Regex`.

Comment: Oops! wouldn't it be nice to have `matches` defined in `Regex`?

Comment: @schmmd, thanks for the idea. You can use the conventional String.matches method and recycle your previously defined `Regex` like this : `"david@example.com".matches(Email.toString)` -> will return `true`.

Comment: @David Wouldn't the above given regex `"""(\w+)@([\w\.]+)""".r` would parse `abc@gmail_com` as valid email ?
Shouldn't the regex be `"""(\w+)@([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)""".r` ?

Answer (score 16):

I created a little "Pimp my Library" pattern for that problem.  Maybe it'll help you out.

```
import util.matching.Regex

object RegexUtils {
  class RichRegex(self: Regex) {
    def =~(s: String) = self.pattern.matcher(s).matches
  }
  implicit def regexToRichRegex(r: Regex) = new RichRegex(r)
}
```

Example of use

```
scala> import RegexUtils._
scala> """\w+""".r =~ "foo"
res12: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Cool!  Though I'd call the operator `~` rather than `~=` because operators that end in `=` look to me like in-place mutations (from C++ and Python conventions...).

Comment: Yeah, I was aiming for perl's =~ but got the name backwards, apparently.

Comment: Just thought I'd mention Haskell has a the =~ operator for matching regexes too. I've seen `~=` used to mean not-equals, like `!=`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys.  I've edited the answer to reflect your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use

```
val regex = "...".r
if (regex.findFirstIn(text).isDefined) ...
```

but I think that is pretty awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (Aug 2014, Scala 2.11) @David's reply tells the norm.

However, it seems the `r."..."` string interpolator may be on its way to help with this. See [How to pattern match using regular expression in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636610/regular-expression-and-pattern-matching-in-scala#16256935)