# Get lines that start with certain characters in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
ABC gibberish
DEF gibberish
ABC text
DEF random
```

I only want to keep the lines that start with **ABC**. This is what I've tried:

```
val lines = sc.textFile("textfile.txt")
val reg = "^ABC".r
val abc_lines = lines.filter(x => reg.pattern.matcher(x).matches)
abc_lines.count()
```

The count returns 0 so nothing matches, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this, you can just the startsWith method.

```
val abc_lines = lines.filter(x => x.startsWith("ABC"))
```

Comment: Ok thanks! But can you also tell me what is wrong about my code?

Answer (score 1):

Because method matches is not doing what you expect(please, see in documentation).

You can try this snippet to understand

```
val list = List("ABC", "DEF gibberish", "ABC text", "DEF random")
val reg = "^ABC".r
val lines: Seq[String] = list.filter(x => reg.pattern.matcher(x).matches)
println(lines.size)
```

Instead, you can use this code:

```
val list2 = List("ABC", "DEF gibberish", "ABC text", "DEF random")
val lines2: Seq[String] = list.filter(reg.findFirstIn(_).isDefined)
println(lines2.size)
```

You can find more info here - [Matching against a regular expression in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301858/matching-against-a-regular-expression-in-scala)

Comment: But,yes, in this simple case you don't need regex.

Comment: Thanks, this also helps me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `findFirstIn` method of *regex* as following

```
val abc_lines = lines.filter(x => "^ABC".r.findFirstIn(x) == Some("ABC"))
```

which should give you the correct result.

**doing as the following would give you `Task not serializable` error message in spark**

```
val reg = "^ABC".r
val abc_lines = lines.filter(x => reg.findFirstIn(x) == Some("ABC"))
```