# How to use pattern matching with regular expressions

Tags: scala

Below code is what I am using to parse a href link from a file :

```
  def parseFile(){
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\Adrian\\Desktop\\parsefile.txt")
    val lines = source.getLines
    val Pattern = "\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\\\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))"

    for (line <- source.getLines) {
        println(line)
    line match {
        case Pattern(c) => println(c)
        case _ => None
    }
   }

    source.close ()
  }
```

A sample line from the parsefile :

```
  <A HREF="www.google.com" title="test">test</A>
```

But I receive this Eclipse compile time error :

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - not found: value c
    - value Pattern is not a case class constructor, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq method
```

How should 'c' be declared in order to access the capture group String ?

I'm basing above code on accepted answer from this question :

[How to pattern match using regular expression in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636610/regex-and-pattern-matching-in-scala) where the code used is :

```
val Pattern = "([a-cA-C])".r
word.firstLetter match {
   case Pattern(c) => c bound to capture group here
   case _ =>
}
```

Any suggestions on a alternative methods to parse the file welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a notable difference between your code:

```
val Pattern = "\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\\\"([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+))"
```

and the example:

```
val Pattern = "([a-cA-C])".r
```

Note the ending `.r`. That converts the String to a regexp pattern. The regexp pattern has a unaplySeq method, so it works with pattern matching.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `Pattern` is `String`, but should be `Regex`. Simply add a call to `.r` to your pattern string.