# Scala array pattern matching using regular expressions

Tags: arrays, string, scala, pattern-matching

How to pattern-match for instance the first string element in an array using regular expressions?

Consider for example

```
Array("col",1) match {
  case Array("""col | row""", n, _*) => n
  case _ => 0
}
```

which delivers `0`, although the desired result would be 1.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A [`Regex`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex) instance provides extractors automatically, so you can use one directly in a pattern match expression:**

```
val regex = "col|row".r

Array("col",1) match {
  case Array(regex(), n, _*) => n
  case _ => 0
}
```

---

Also: in a more general QA about regexps in Scala, sschaef has [provided a very nice string interpolation for pattern matching usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16256935/724361) (e.g. `r"col|row"` in this example). A potential caveat: the interpolation creates a fresh `Regex` instance on every call - so, if you use the same regex a large number of times, it *may* more efficient to store it in a `val` instead (as in this answer).

Comment: That is definitely better than my solution

Comment: @serejja : well, potentially more efficient, and arguably more readable - maybe ;). Thanks in any case.

Comment: Many Thanks for alĺ the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it is the best solution, but the working one:

```
Array("col", 1) match {
  case Array(str: String, n, _*) if str.matches("col|row") => n //note that spaces are removed in the pattern
  case _ => 0
}
```

Comment: Note that it's an `Array[Any]` and your result is also still `Any`.