# Split string with default value in scala

Tags: scala, tuples, default-value

I have a list of strings as shown below, which lists fruits and the cost associated with each. In case of no value, it is assumed to be 5:

```
val stringList: List[String] = List("apples 20", "oranges", "pears 10")
```

Now I want to split the string to get tuples of the fruit and the cost. What is the scala way of doing this?

```
stringList.map(query => query.split(" "))
```

is not what I want.

I [found this](https://reidarsollid.com/2013/04/23/string-split-method-to-return-a-tuple/) which is similar. What is the correct Scala way of doing this?

Comment: Map a custom function that splits and then adds an element if the second is missing.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regular expression and pattern matching:

```
val Pat = """(.+)\s(\d+)""".r  // word followed by whitespace followed by number

def extract(in: String): (String, Int) = in match {
  case Pat(name, price) => (name, price.toInt)
  case _                => (in, 5)
}

val stringList: List[String] = List("apples 20", "oranges", "pears 10")

stringList.map(extract) // List((apples,20), (oranges,5), (pears,10))
```

You have two capturing groups in the pattern. These will be extracted as strings, so you have to convert explicitly using `.toInt`.

Comment: Here is a bit more on pattern matching: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636610/how-to-pattern-match-using-regular-expression-in-scala

Comment: `val r = """(\S+)\s*(\d+)?""".r ; def f(s: String) = s match { case r(n, null) => (n, 42) case r(n, i) => (n, i.toInt) case _ => (0,0) }` to show handling empty second group. Regex helps so much with verifying.

Comment: @som-snytt Thanks, my regex foo is rather limited

Answer (score 3):

You almost have it:

```
stringList.map(query => query.split(" "))
```

*is* what you want, just add another map to it to change lists to tuples:

```
.map { list => list.head -> list.lift(1).getOrElse("5").toInt }
```

or this instead, if you prefer:

```
.collect { 
    case Seq(a, b) => a -> b.toInt
    case Seq(a) => a -> 5
 }
```

(`.collect` will silently ignore the occurrences, where there are less than one or more than two elements in the list. You can replace it with `.map` if you would prefer it to through an error in such cases).