# Scala regex pattern matching with String Interpolation

Tags: regex, scala

From Scala 2.10 we can define new method r using StringContext like this:

```
implicit class RegexContext(sc: StringContext) {
  def r = new Regex(sc.parts.mkString, sc.parts.tail.map(_ => "x"): _*)
}
```

Then we can easily define regex pattern after case keyword like this:

```
"123" match { 
   case r"\d+" => true 
   case _ => false 
}
```

Which is not clear to me how the implementation inside of the implicit class `RegexContext` works

Can someone explain to me the implementation of the method `r`, especially `sc.parts.tail.map(_ => "x"): _*`?

The implementation is taken from [How to pattern match using regular expression in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636610/how-to-pattern-match-using-regular-expression-in-scala/16256935#16256935)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Regex` constructor takes two arguments.

> new **Regex**(regex: String, groupNames: String*)

The `groupNames` parameter is a vararg so it (they) are actually optional and, in this case, it should have been left empty because that `groupNames` code is pretty useless.

Let's review what `groupNames` is supposed to do. We'll start without `groupNames`.

```
val rx = new Regex("~(A(.)C)~")  // pattern with 2 groups, no group names
rx.findAllIn("~ABC~").group(0) //res0: String = ~ABC~
rx.findAllIn("~ABC~").group(1) //res1: String = ABC
rx.findAllIn("~ABC~").group(2) //res2: String = B
rx.findAllIn("~ABC~").group(3) //java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 3
```

And now with `groupNames`.

```
val rx = new Regex("~(A(.)C)~", "x", "y", "z")  // 3 groups named
rx.findAllIn("~ABC~").group("x") //res0: String = ABC
rx.findAllIn("~ABC~").group("y") //res1: String = B
rx.findAllIn("~ABC~").group("z") //java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 3
```

So why is `sc.parts.tail.map(_ => "x"): _*` so useless? First because the number of names created is unrelated to the number of groups in the pattern, but also because it uses the same string, `"x"`, for every name it specifies. That name will only be good for the last group named.

```
val rx = new Regex("~(A(.)C)~", "x", "x")  // 2 groups named
rx.findAllIn("~ABC~").group("x") //res0: String = B (i.e. group(2))
```

...and...

```
val rx = new Regex("~(A(.)C)~", "x", "x", "x")  // 3 groups named
rx.findAllIn("~ABC~").group("x") //java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Those args are group names, not very useful here.

```
scala 2.13.0-M5> implicit class R(sc: StringContext) { def r = sc.parts.mkString.r }
defined class R

scala 2.13.0-M5> "hello" match { case r"hell.*" => }
```

Compare:

```
scala 2.13.0-M5> implicit class R(sc: StringContext) { def r = sc.parts.mkString("(.*)").r }
defined class R

scala 2.13.0-M5> "hello" match { case r"hell$x" => x }
res5: String = o
```